connecting my OrangePi Zero2 (Orange Os Arch ARM64) with Arduino Mega Pro Mini by pins or bluetooth
I would like some help with connecting my OrangePi Zero2 (Orange Os Arch[ArchLinux ARM64 based]) with an Arduino Mega Pro Mini in two ways:

TTL (rx tx pins) [no success up until now]
SPP (Bluetooth serial) [success in some moments through minicom or bluetooth devices GUI]

The objective of the connection is to make the 2 devices communicate exchanging data and receiving commands from a C# App. This program used to run in an OrangePi already, but with Android System, and now it's migrating.
About TTL

I already tried to enable the UART5 in /boot/extlinux/extlinux.config, no success.
Also tried putting on high level through wiringPO (gpio) with gpio write 3/4 and altering mode to OUT or IN, it does changes, but there isn't any differences in the ports.  Also tried setting modes to ALT2, but it doesn't set.
The command dmesg | grep ttyS is returning:
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: initrd=/initramfs-linux.img console=ttyS0,115200 root=PARTUUID=2b109420-02 rw rootwait audit=0 splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles overlays=uart5
[    1.935042] printk: console [ttyS0] disabled
[    1.935189] 5000000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x5000000 (irq = 286, base_baud = 1500000) is a 16550A
[    3.275468] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    9.392514] systemd[1]: Expecting device /dev/ttyS0...

About SPP

It doesn't connect at first try. I have to try 2 or 3 times, and then the connection establishes. Works better in minicom and sometimes in the native bluetooth GUI.
In minicom, it doesn't show my input, but if type and enter, the arduino receives it.
It should work through InTheHand for an C# App, but it isn't connecting. I don't have more information because I don't get outputs for the connection error and can't access the source code of the app.

